# I can't get springboot devtools to work

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I'm using STS 3.8.4, I've placed the spring devtools dependency on my pom.xml, I tried to run my springboot project on the IDE, went to a page (template using thymeleaf) and tried to modify something on the template, I hit refresh but nothing happens. Is there any other configuration needed? I also tried setting thymeleaf caching to false but still no luck. Below is my pom.xml.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.emil</groupId>
  <artifactId>inventory</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>inventory</name>
  <description>Inventory System in Spring</description>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
    <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

[Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuFDl.png)
[Log 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ih7lj.png)

Comment: You may need to turn off the cache for thymeleaf.  See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43147157/spring-boot-devtools-not-working-in-eclipse/43147726#43147726

Comment: It's not working. my application.properties looks like this.

Comment: spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/inventory
spring.datasource.username= root
spring.datasource.password = root
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false

Comment: have you checked to see if you're browser is caching the templates?  While its running try and clear your browser cache and see if it updates

Comment: tried it but still  not working

Comment: I found an issue reported on github for this same issue.  amr provides a possible solution.. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/34#issuecomment-68209652

Comment: It's not just templates though even java classes. I tried modifying them all.

Comment: did you clean and rebuild the project after adding the devtools dependency?

Comment: yes. A couple of times.

Comment: I tried cleaning the .m2 repository folder, building and cleaning the project but its still not working.

Comment: What does the log output look like when you start your app?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I've added screenshots of my log

Comment: Screenshots are of minimal use unfortunately. The top of the first screenshot shows some debug output that lists the URLs that are being watched for changes. It's worth checking that the URLs that are shown match the locations into which Eclipse is compiling your code

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Matching URLs for reloading : [file:/C:/Users/Emilio/Documents/workspace-sts-3.8.4.RELEASE/inventory/target/classes/] when I open that folder I can only see two files, pom.properties and pom.xml, do you have any recomendations on how to make springdevtools work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution. The problem was my eclipse is not automatically building the project upon saving.